# CSS identifier hints in NetBeans 7.1 IDE

Tags: css, netbeans, dreamweaver, hints

I recently made the change from Dreamweaver to NetBeans and noticed this IDE doesn't have anything out-of-the-box to display identifier options for CSS. For example, if I type

```
list-style:
```

I would expect a scroll menu to appear with my choices for this identifier. This is helpful for people like me who don't memorize every single CSS option under the sun!

Any plugins around for this?

Comment: check `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code completion -> HTML ->`, NetBeans 7.1 should have auto-complete for CSS out of the box.

Comment: It's enabled already. The auto-complete feature itself appears to be working just always giving me a 'No Suggestions' syntax instead of options.

Comment: Well, opened a new, clean css file and it's working properly so I think I might have a syntax error somewhere that prevents it from working yet is still being parsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write single letter of desired value it will pop-up after second or two ( or at least it do on my Netbeans 7.0 )

or hit Ctrl + Space

Comment: Alright, well what you suggested works just like you said while working on html or php, but always shows 'no suggestions' in a css file.

Comment: eh. then you have some fails in your setup or configuration, i have Netbeans out of the box with PHP, HTML, Java and CSS auto-completion. Or it can be caused by syntax error somwhere in file